# Reading CSV with Perl produces distorted lines

Tags: perl

I am reading a CSV file using Perl 5.26.1 with lines that look like this:

> B1_10,202337840166,R08C02,202337840166_R08C02.gtc

I'm reading this data into a hash that has the last element as a key, and the first as a value.

I read the file line by line (snippet only):

```
while (<$csv>) {
    if (/^Sample/) { next }
    say "-----start----\noriginal = $_";
    chomp;
    my @line = split /,/;
    my $name = $line[0];
    my $vcf  = $line[3];
    say "1st element = $name";
    say "4th element = $vcf";
    $vcf2dir{$vcf} = $name;
    say "\$vcf2dir{$vcf} = '$name'";
    say '-----end------';
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
-----start----
original = B1_10,202337840166,R08C02,202337840166_R08C02.gtc

1st element = B1_10
4th element = 202337840166_R08C02.gtc
} = 'B1_10'2337840166_R08C02.gtc
-----end-------
```

but it should look like

```
-----start----
original = B1_10,202337840166,R08C02,202337840166_R08C02.gtc

1st element = B1_10
4th element = 202337840166_R08C02.gtc
$vcf2dir{202337840166_R08C02.gtc} = 'B1_10'
-----end-------
```

and it shows strangely with the data printer package:

```
use DDP;
p %vcf2dir;
```

produces

```
{
'   "B1_10"840166_R08C02.gtc
}
```

in other words, the last string is being cut up for some reason.
I have tried removing non-ascii characters with `$_ =~ s/[[:^ascii:]]//g;` but this still produces the same error.

I have no idea why Perl is ripping these strings apart :(

Comment: The closest thing to a CSV standard (rfc4180) says to use CRLF line endings, btw, even on non Windows OSes. Using an actual CSV parser like [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) addresses this and many other potential issues and is the best approach for any non-trivial data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your snippet against your line and it worked as expected
But I have had behavior like what you show because a spurious Control-M's in my data.

Try filtering for control-M's 
after your chomp replace all control-M's with the command below

```
s/\cM//g;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while (<$csv>) {
    ...
    chomp;
```

My guess is that the input file has as line end `\r\n` (windows style) while you are executing the code in a UNIX like environment (Linux, Mac...) where the line end is `\n`. This means that `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` is also `\n` and that `chomp` only removes the `\n` and leaves the `\r`. This left `\r` causes such strange output.

To fix this either fix the line endings in your input file, set `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` to the expected separator or just do `s{\r?\n\z}{}` instead of `chomp` to handle both `\r\n` and `\n` line endings.

Comment: your solution works as well. I have two answers that work, but I can't accept both :(